# This piece of PHP code with Javascript / jQ... How?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<?php
            if(strstr(file_get_contents('http://api.alphenweer.nl/api.php?apikey=Hier uw api sleutel&server=servercheck'), '1')){
                echo 'AlphenWeer.nl Api server is online en werkend.';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'AlphenWeer.nl Api server if offline of niet werkend, of uw API code klopt niet.';
            }
    ?>
```

How can i do this with javascript and/or jQuery?
I only know the AJAX part, but then check if 1 is in the data.. How?

Comment: What does the returned data look like? Is it just "1" or "0" ?

Comment: it is a string like this "Api was not correct - Error code 2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `indexOf` method described in [the Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
if (str.indexOf('1')>-1) {
    // found
}
else 
{
    // not found
}
```

where `str` contains the string returned by your AJAX part.